# How to use fzero in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, equation

I would like to use `fzero` to approximate the root of

```
x+sin(x)=e^x
```

close to -1.

However, `fzero` just seems to return the guess I provide:

```
> fzero('x+sin(x)==e^x', -1)
-1
> fzero('x+sin(x)==e^x', -4) 
-4
```

The actual answer should be -.354. What is my issue here?

Comment: I think Luis has answered your problem adequately. Please consider accepting his answer

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems in your code:

- [`fzero`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fzero.html) tries to find a zero of the *function* supplied as first argument. You are supplying an equation, not a function.
- Matlab doesn't know what `e` is. Use [`exp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/exp.html).
- The equation `x+sin(x)==exp(x)` doesn't seem to have real solutions. You probably mean `x+sin(x)==-exp(x)`.

Taking these three things into account, the function whose zero you want to compute is, in string form,`'x+sin(x)+exp(x)'`. So:

```
>> fzero('x+sin(x)+exp(x)', -1)
ans =
   -0.3545
```

As noted by @rayryeng, `fzero` also accepts a [function handle](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/function_handle.html) to define its input function. In fact, as observed by @horchler, using a string is currently *undocumented*, and it's  *slower*. Therefore, it's recommended to define the function to be passed to `fzero` in the form of a function handle. In your case, you could directly use an [anonymous function](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html) as follows:

```
>> fzero(@(x) x+sin(x)+exp(x), -1)
ans =
   -0.3545
```

Comment: `fzero` can also take in an anonymous function, but I'm sure you already knew that!

Comment: @rayryeng Yep :-) I used string because the OP did. But this is a good hint!

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the correction! I typed too fast :-D

Comment: Hehe sorry... I saw you were actively editing it, and I waited a few minutes to see if you caught that spelling error, but I didn't see that you caught it so I decided to fix it for you lol. Sorry.  The typo stared at me like it needed to be corrected.

Comment: @rayryeng I was editing to incorporate your comment. But I'm not sure if it's better to just leave it as a comment. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm... yeah leaving as a comment is fine.  It's not within the scope of the OP's question.

Comment: In recent versions of Matlab, the string option appears to be completely undocumented. It could theoretically be entirely removed in the future. It's also slower than using an anonymous function (by 5–6 times for 100 `fzero` calls with the OP's function).